# MySQL Connecting with Blank User Name & Password

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos8

I'm having serious trouble for the last few days, please have empathy with my question.

After a series of server crashes and hackings, today I've found out that my mysql can be connected via a web interface without a username and password. Is this even possible? I think i'm close to losing my sanity.

Please help me some one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I had set skip-grant-tables in my.cnf while trying to perform some user management work which had caused this. Phew. The panic, the sanity. I hope this helps someone.